# How do I understand YOLO gride cell

Tags: bounding-box, yolo

"Our system divides the input image into an S * S grid.
If the center of an object falls into a grid cell, that grid cell
is responsible for detecting that object."

This is from YOLO paper, the input images are divided into S*S grid,which means that the output of conv is the size of S * S, right?

If so, how do these small cells(7 * 7) connect to the original region of input image? I know how conv works, but how the bounding boxes do regression?

Answer (score 0):

The ground truth in original size will be "resized" to SxS, in this case 7x7 in Yolov1 or 13x13 in Yolov2
I think this Yolo implementation could be useful for you to understand how yolo built:
https://github.com/1991viet/Yolo-pytorch

Comment: the git repo isnt available now